# How To Dynamically Change Properties In ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

So in my DAO, I have a query like this

```
@Query("Select * from transaction_history where wallet_type=:walletType AND email=:email AND transaction_type='Expenses' AND date BETWEEN :from AND :to")
fun getLastSevenDaysExpensesTransaction(walletType: String, email:String, from: Long?, to: Long?) : LiveData<List<ExpensesTransaction>>?

@Query("Select * from transaction_history where wallet_type=:walletType AND email=:email AND transaction_type='Income' AND date BETWEEN :from AND :to")
fun getLastSevenIncomeTransaction(walletType: String, email:String, from: Long?, to: Long?) : LiveData<List<IncomeTransaction>>
```

And in my viewModel, this is how I call getLastSevenDaysExpensesTransaction method

```
class GraphViewModel(dataSource: NetWalletDatabaseDao, application: Application, email: String, walletType: String) : ViewModel() {

val database = dataSource

var from : Long = 0L

var to : Long = 0L

val lastSevenDaysIncome = database.getLastSevenIncomeTransaction(walletType, email, from, to)

val lastSevenDaysExpenses = database.getLastSevenDaysExpensesTransaction(walletType, email, from, to)

fun funcLastSevenDaysIncome(fromParam: Long, toParam: Long) {
    from = fromParam
    to = toParam
}
```

And in my Fragment, this is how I display the data

```
val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
    val dataSource = NetWalletDatabase.getInstance(application).netWalletDatabaseDao
    val viewModelFactory = GraphViewModelFactory(
        dataSource,
        application,
        getEmail.toString(),
        getWalletType.toString(),
    )
    val viewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(GraphViewModel::class.java)


    val tvLastSevenDays = binding.tvLastSevenDays
    viewModel.funcLastSevenDaysIncome(sevenDaysInMili, todayMili)

    val chart : LineChart = binding.chart
    val expenses = ArrayList<Entry>()
    viewModel.lastSevenDaysMut.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
        list?.let {
            for (i in 0..list.size - 1) {
                expenses.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), list.get(i).value!!.toFloat()))

            }
            Log.e("Result", list.get(0).value!!.toString())
        }
        val expensesLineDataSet = LineDataSet(expenses, "Expenses")
        expensesLineDataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
        expensesLineDataSet.color = Color.BLUE
        expensesLineDataSet.circleRadius = 5f
        expensesLineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE)

        val income = ArrayList<Entry>()
        viewModel.lastSevenDaysMut.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { list ->
            list?.let {
                for (i in 0..list.size - 1) {
                    income.add(Entry(i.toFloat(), list.get(i).value!!.toFloat()))

                    Log.e("Result", list.get(0).value!!.toString())

                }
            }
            val incomeLineDataSet = LineDataSet(income, "Income")
            incomeLineDataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
            incomeLineDataSet.color = Color.RED
            incomeLineDataSet.circleRadius = 5f
            incomeLineDataSet.setCircleColor(Color.RED)

            val legend = chart.legend
            legend.isEnabled = true
            legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP)
            legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
            legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL)
            legend.setDrawInside(false)

            chart.description.isEnabled = false
            chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            chart.data = LineData(expensesLineDataSet, incomeLineDataSet)
            chart.animateXY(100, 500)
        })
    })
```

The problem is that the data won't show. What I understand so far why the data won't show is that, when `val lastSevenDaysIncome = database.getLastSevenIncomeTransaction(walletType, email, from, to)` and `val lastSevenDaysExpenses = database.getLastSevenDaysExpensesTransaction(walletType, email, from, to)` from my viewModel is run, the properties of `var from : Long = 0L` and `var to : Long = 0L` is still zero even though in my Fragment, I have called the method to change those properties `viewModel.funcLastSevenDaysIncome(sevenDaysInMili, todayMili)`.

So how do I fix it? How do I change the properties `var from : Long = 0L` and `var to : Long = 0L` before they are used for query?

P.S. I used to put all the necessary parameters for query in constructor. For example

```
class GraphViewModel(dataSource: NetWalletDatabaseDao, application: Application, email: String, walletType: String, from: Long, to: Long) : ViewModel()
```

and use it for example

```
val lastSevenDaysIncome = database.getLastSevenIncomeTransaction(walletType, email, from, to)
```

But, since "from" and "to" is dynamic, I can't use it anymore because then in my fragment, I have to initialize the viewModelProvider something like this

```
val viewModelFactory = GraphViewModelFactory(
    dataSource,
    application,
    getEmail.toString(),
    getWalletType.toString(),
***dynamic from*
*dynamic to***
)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you debugged them to know that are being passed as zero to room database or you think that might be the issue ?

Comment: I don't know if I did a proper debugging or no. But I tried hardcoded changing the properties value and yes, the data did show. So I concluded that the properties are still zero when it passed to room database. I don't know what I'm missing, but I think it runs val lastSevenDaysIncome = database.getLastSevenIncomeTransaction(walletType, email, from, to) first then fun funcLastSevenDaysIncome(fromParam: Long, toParam: Long) {
    from = fromParam
    to = toParam
} Even though in my fragment, I called funcLastSeven() first then observe lastSevenDays